# convert image buffer to filestream

Tags: c++, image, buffer, filestream, streambuf

Something similar to this may have been asked earlier, I could not find an exact answer to my problem to decided to ask here.
I am working with a 3rd party framework that has it's own classes defined to handle image files. It only accepts the file name and the whole implementation is around being able to open these filestreams and perform reads/writes.
I'd like to input an image buffer (that I obtain through some pre-processing on an image open earlier) and feed it to this framework. The problem being I cannot feed a buffer to it, only a filename string.

I am looking at the best way to convert my buffer to a filestream so it can be seekable and be ingested by the framework. Please help me figure out what I should be looking at.
I tried reading about streambuf (filebuf and stringbuf) and tried assigning the buffer to these types, but no success so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the framework only takes a file name, then you have to pass it a file name.  Which means the data must reside in the file system.

The portable answer is "write your data to a temporary file and pass the name of that".

On Unix, you might be able to use a named pipe and fork another thread to feed the data through the pipe...

But honestly, you are probably better off just using a temporary file.  If you manage to open, read, and delete the file quickly enough, it most likely will never make it out to disk anyway, since the kernel will cache the data.

And if you are able to use a ramdisk (tmpfs), you can guarantee that everything happens in memory.

[edit]

One more thought.  If you can modify your code base to operate on `std::iostream` instead of `std::fstream`, you can pass it a `std::stringstream`.  They support all of the usual `iostream` operations on a memory buffer, including things like seeking.

Comment: Thanks, so is there no way in c++ that a char buffer can be made to resemble a filestream?

Comment: tmpfs on my system seems to be at /dev/shm. /tmp is on the disk for me. Plus I am intending to farm this task of processing thousands of images to a queue. Would trying to do this in the memory of queue machines still work satisfactorily? Thanks

Comment: Your question says it takes a "file name"...  What data type does the function actually take?

Comment: /dev/shm is how Linux glibc implements `shm_open`.  You are not really supposed to use it directly...  If you want to go the tmpfs route, you are better off creating one yourself (it's one line in /etc/fstab).  As for "thousands of images", you need to worry about the memory consumption of those, anyway.  tmpfs is just another way to allocate memory.

Comment: (const char* fname). It then goes on to open this and chunk through data by seeking to it's header etc. Getting it's tiff directory etc.

Comment: Right, so even if you could create a magic `fstream` object, there would be no way to pass it to the function.  You have to arrange for the data to appear in the file system.  Simple files, files on a tmpfs, and named pipes are your best bets.

Comment: guess I could define a mountpoint, but unfortunately cannot do that with the queue machines that are under strict maintenance of the systems folks :( I worry about the excessive overhead of writing, reading deleting files. Makes me curse the framework writers. Really, how tough would it have been for them to write a parallel approach for buffered input? Am I thinking on the right lines here?

Comment: I have access to their giant source code base and even tried re-implementing some of the methods to take in a buffer, but it was too deeply rooted in the filestream idea that it soon became impractical.

Comment: I have updated my answer with one more suggestion.  May or may not work for you depending on what your library is actually doing and how much room you have to modify it.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will definitely try it and report back here.